Magento 2 : Website Become Slow after Updating Tax Configuration
We currently have a stable website on magento 2.4.6 version with Elasticsearch and Redis-server.
Websites is very responsive and fast, until we update tax configuration. When we change default tax configuration, site starts to become slower, atleast response is reduced by 2-3 seconds on each request.
Site is based for European customers, so having tax automation is essential. Any suggestions, as to why it can be happening?
